# discord.py: Time object in embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wondered if it was possible to build something like this:[image: example]

So that it can be put into an embed and shows the time. However when I looked through the discord.py docs I could not find this type of object. Searched google but no solutions. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Those are not Discord.py specific, actually. The special markup you see there is a timestamp style, see https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-timestamp-styles.

The format is usually `<t:UNIX_TIMESTAMP>` or `<t:UNIX_TIMESTAMP:STYLE>`, where style is one of the options in the link above. These show up in the user's TZ.

To wrap up, they are just plain-text, Discord-specific styles you can place in normal messages, as well as embeds (just not in the certain places, like the footer).